# How to Retrieve data from firebase realtime database according to App Language on Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

[Pic of my database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERH8e.png) I'm trying to get data from the firebase real-time database to a GridView builder using Stream builder according to the app language. But I don't know how to check the App language before choosing the child I'm getting the data from.

```js
 Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 90.0),
            child: Scaffold(
                key: _scaffoldKey,
                body: Column(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                        child: StreamBuilder(
                      stream: FirebaseDatabase.instance
                          .reference()
                          .child('CleaningList')
                          .onValue,
                      builder: (BuildContext context,
                          AsyncSnapshot<Event> snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          var map = snapshot.data.snapshot.value
                              as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;
                          clothesModels.clear();
                          map.forEach((key, value) {
                            var clothesModel = new ClothesModel.fromJson(
                                json.decode(json.encode(value)));
                            clothesModel.key = key;
                            clothesModels.add(clothesModel);
                          });
                          return GridView.builder(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                  top: 20.0, right: 26.0, left: 26.0),
                              itemCount: clothesModels.length,
                              gridDelegate:
                                  SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                crossAxisCount: 2,
                              ),
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                                    child: Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                      children: [
                                        Container(
                                          child: Center(
                                              child: Image.network(
                                                clothesModels[index].image,
                                            width: 40.0,
                                            height: 50.0,
                                          )),
                                        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Check app language.

> Locale myLocale = Localizations.localeOf(context);

provides `languageCode`.

Visit [localeDocs](https://flutter.io/tutorials/internationalization/#tracking-locale) for more information.